# sendBroadcast exception(NullPointerException) in a new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-broadcast

I'm sending a "Broadcast" from a new thread. and get an error of "java.lang.NullPointerException at com.internectics.fragment.AddPackFragment$6.run". I highlight something here:
1. these codes is within a subclass of DialogFragment
2. if I remove the line of "getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);", it will be no exception. So I believe it is the root cause.

Appreciate if anybody could comment on my question and help me out of it

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //some other codes skipped here, including saving data to persistence
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Global.BROADCAST_ACTION_UPDATE_MASTER_VIEW);
                    intent.putExtra(Global.KEY_FROM, Global.BROADCAST_EXTRA_FROM_NEW_PACK);
                    getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            });
        };
    }.start();
```

Comment: Can you get a final reference to your activity before executing your thread, and use that one in your run method ? be sure to check it is not null before using it

Comment: All right I will remove my comment and put an answer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear, why do you need a new thread with runOnUiThread(...) for this action. Accordingly to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29:

```
This call is asynchronous; it returns immediately, and you will continue executing while the receivers are run.
```

Comment: Also check, if getActivity() doesn't return null in your code. But anyway, new thread is causeless in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, there're some codes(saving  data to persistence) just before "Intent intent = new Intent();"

Comment: Thanks, you are right, getActivity() is null, but how could it be null? if I put getActivity() out of this new thread, it is NOT null.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get a final reference to your activity before executing your thread, and use that one in your run method ? be sure to check it is not null before using it